# Viewbased project is not using MainWindow.xib

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using x-code 4 and any time I start a "view based application" (say "Test") IB opens up and creates 6 files.  1)TestAppDelicate.h 2)TestAppDelicate.m 3)MainWindow.xib 4)TestViewController.h 5)TestViewController.m 6)TestViewController.xib

Now the Main Interface is set to MainWindow yet when I run the app it always starts up the TestViewController.xib not mainwindow.

The problem is If I change from iPhone to Universal app it creates a MainWindow-ipad.xib that is unusable. How do I get it to use mainwindow?

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong or am I uninformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MainWindow.xib creates the root window and sets it's view controller to the TestViewController. TestViewController's contents are created in the TestViewController.xib.

In other words, you ARE using the main window.

Comment: OH! I see said the Blind man as he picked up his hammer and saw.  Then  how do I set the size and layout for the ipad? I create a new xib and set the view controller from the mainwindow-ipad.xib to that one. But how do you set that?

Comment: In the "Summary" or "Info" pages for the project, you select the XIB file for the main window. If you're building a universal project, they have a space to select one for each format.